# How do I search all hidden files that are in hidden folders using Terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder, spotlight, unix

I need to find some configs buried in some hidden folders and can't recall where they are to navigate to them directly <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

I did a `sudo find -name Foo*` (slow), but none of the returned files were in hidden folders.

What is the easiest way to search all hidden files?

Comment: Note: Using `sudo` is unnecessary unless you need to search in directories that you do not have access to. Searching in hidden directories does not require elevated privileges, if that's why it's being used in your example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`mdfind` seems to ignore a lot of hidden files. `mdfind 'kMDItemFSInvisible==1&&kMDItemFSName==filename'` does list `.DS_Store` files, but not for example `.bash_history`. I haven't found any way to search for files in some hidden directories like `/private/etc/`.

Anyway, [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php) is a lot faster than `find`.

[image]

> Find Any File is a program for Mac OS X that lets you search for files on your disks.
>
> - Contrary to Spotlight, it does not use a database but instead uses the file system driver's fast search operations, where available. This lets you search for file properties such as name, dates, size, etc., but not for file content (use Spotlight or EasyFind for that).
> - Find Any File can find files that Spotlight doesn't, e.g. those inside bundles and packages and in inside folders that are usually excluded from Spotlight search.
> - Finally, it is quite fast. A search only takes a few seconds on an internal hard disk or SSD. Try for yourself!

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that by “hidden file” you mean files whose name begins with a dot or that are located somewhere under a directory whose name begins with a dot, and not [other forms of invisible files](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/invisibles.html), the following command prints the names of all hidden files. It's slow as it goes over all the file names everywhere on your system.

```
sudo find / -name '.*' \( -type d -exec find {} \; -prune -o -print \)
```

Explanation:

- `-type d -exec find {} \; -prune` executes `find` on every directory (whose name matched `.*`), and skips descending into that directory because of the `-prune`.
- `-type d … -o -print` causes all non-directories that match `.*` to be printed.

If you're looking for a file with a specific name or pattern:

```
sudo find / -name 'Foo*' -path '*/.*'
```

The `*/.*` pattern on the whole path forces matches to be under a hidden directory.

You may want to add `-xdev` after the `/` to avoid traversing special filesystems and removable disks.

Comment: Ah, thanks. And it looks like -x is preferred now, as -xdev is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Try the `locate` command. You will have to `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` first and wait for the locate DB to be generated.

Comment: It's such a nuisance that Spotlight doesn't pick up hidden / (dot-)files, because mdfind is vastly superior to slocate.

Comment: In recent macOS versions, this is no longer a real solution -- the locate.updatedb command is run using the _nobody_ user, which does not have permission to view files in user home directories, which most people probably want

Answer (score 2):

**EasyFind** is an excellent alternative app to get the job done. It's free and easy.
You can search for text in files (even invisible ones). <= This may be an easier way to find your config files.

You can get it from the App Store
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12

Disclaimer: *I am not affiliated with the developer.*

Comment: Does not work on APFS-formatted drives.

Answer (score 2):

**ag can search hidden files by file name.**

For instance:

```
ag --hidden -g ".swiftlint.yml" ~/
```

How to install

```
brew install the_silver_searcher
```

https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

**rg is faster than ag.**

```
rg --files --hidden ~/ |rg  ".swiftlint.yml"
```

How to install

```
brew install ripgrep
```

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

Comment: How does this help in the situation described by the OP (who apparently doesn't know the name of the hidden files)?

Comment: It works as well. For instance, rg --files --hidden ~/ |rg  ".swiftlint*"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to search **.DS_Store** hidden files, this command works well.

```
du -a | grep .DS_Store
```