# locate isn't finding a file that exists

Tags: macos, terminal

The file in question is:

`/Users/me/Library/Containers/com.dell.Toad/Data/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.dell.toadext.oracle.core/connections.xml`

What is wrong with locate?

Comment: Do you have the daemon `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with locate. By default, it doesn't search for/in hidden files/directories.

The directories `/.metadata` and  `/.plugins` are both hidden by the fact they are prefixed with a period "." which means that locate is not going to index the files within those directories.

I prefer to use the `find` command:

`sudo find / -name connections.xml`

Comment: Thank you.  The find command works.  Is there a way to default enable locate to search in hidden directory and for hidden files?  I am used to linux and locate actually locating things.

Comment: I would have to do further research because once I found that it *didn't* search for hidden files way back when without some editing of the .plist file, I abandoned it and went with `find` insead.  Besides, `find` is universal across OS X, FreeBSD, and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `locate` database in built by the script `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. The script is run by the user `nobody` in this line

```
tmpdb=`su -fm nobody -c "$0"` || rc=1
```

unless the user `nobody` has access to a directory then the content of that directory is not recorded in the database. A simple solution would be to use `mdfind`.

```
mdfind -name connections.xml
```

Comment: I tried mdfind connections.xml, it didn't return results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the daemon is running on your machine:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

Alternatively you can also run the following command and build the database:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

**Note**, that indexing of files from the filesystem would take a while, so `locate` will not show you all the files matched immediately.

---

Or you may use the regular [`find`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41043/how-do-i-search-all-hidden-files-that-are-in-hidden-folders-using-terminal) for search of what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If the daemon isn't running ios will tell you to build the locatedb with those commands when you call locate.  I had already run them - I think the problem has to do with hidden directories.